# What's the best way to create linking tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

Still new to Rails.

I'm certain there's a naming convention for what I'm trying to do here.

You've got posts, and then you've got tags (I'm not actually making a blog but this a scenario we're all familiar with).

I'd set up my tags like this:

```
ruby script/generate scaffold tag name:string
```

Then I'd create a linking table like this:

```
ruby script/generate migration x_tag_post tag_id:integer post_id:integer
```

So then in the models I'd have xTagAsset

```
belongs_to :tags
belongs_to :posts
```

And then in Tags *and* Posts I'd say

```
has_many :x_tag_posts
```

Is that the right way to do this? I have a feeling there's something better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the built-in Active Record [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) or [has_many :through =>](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) options

HABTM assumes the existence of a table following some basic conventions and lets you use:

```
class Tags < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :assets 
end 

class Asserts < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags 
end
```

Has Many through explicitly declares the joining table:

```
class Tags < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :assets, :through => "assets_tags"
end 

class Asserts < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :tags, :through => "assets_tags"
end
```

The guides I have linked to above have more details on the implementation.

Comment: Thank you.  I forgot to rename my "assets" to "posts" for the question(woops), so wherever you've got Assets up there it should probably be Posts.  Thanks again, this exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: HABTM doesnt support `dependent: :destroy` so that limits its use

Comment: actually your class name is Asserts, not Assets.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [the has many through association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) like what Toby Hede wrote.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :assets  
  has_many :tags, :through => :assets 
end

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :post  
  belongs_to :tag
end 

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :assets
  has_many :posts, :through => :assets
end
```

Hope that will help :)

Answer (score 0):

From a purely database perspective you create a table called PostTag which looks something like this.  (This is SQL Server syntax, YMMV.)

```
CREATE TABLE PostTag
(PostId INT,
TagId INT
CONSTRAINT PK_PostTag PRIMARY KEY (PostId, TagId))
```

Comment: Thanks, I've done this frequently outside of Rails--I'm more interested in how to do it according to the Rails conventions.

Comment: In addition, if you are using a migration to add the join table make sure you exclude the "id" primary key => "create_table :posts_tags, :id => false do |table|"